# Meteor tutorials (specifically on Ubuntu)

Tags: web-applications, ubuntu, meteor

For the final project in one of my classes, we are tasked with researching something that has to do with web development. After some looking around I came across Meteor, and was really intrigued.

As of right now I know they don't have windows support for version 0.5, so I installed VirtualBox 4.2.2 and Ubuntu 12.10. I won't go into details but I've had all manner of problems with that VM.

I just have a couple questions:
Where are some good actual coding examples/tutorials for Meteor? In terms of web development experience, I have very little.

and

Using Ubuntu, what is the best IDE/editor to use for Meteor? I'm brand new to Ubuntu, and all the tutorials I have seen (visually speaking) are wrote on a Mac (which I don't/won't own).

So far I have done the scoreboard example on meteor.com, but don't have an IDE/Editor installed to actually edit the code.

Answer (score 8):

Meteor is essentially JavaScript, if you have a basic understanding of JavaScript you'll be fine with just the Meteor Documentation, although if you're looking for some tutorials that can show you how to get started here are a good few

A soft introduction and tutorial to Meteor: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/whats-this-meteor-thing/

A basic real time chat room: http://vimeo.com/40300075

HTML5, Bootstrap and Meteor Tutorial: http://vimeo.com/49433252

Pushing Meteor to Heroku: http://bytesofpi.com/post/20898722298/pushing-your-meteor-project-to-heroku

I recommend the first two to get yourself started, make sure you're familiar with what Node.JS is and JavaScript fundamentals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll check those tutorials out and start brushing up more on javascript and nodeJS. So with my second question then, would any IDE/Editor that supports javascript (or just web development all together) work fine for building Meteor apps?

Comment: Yes, Sublime Text 2 is a good Editor.

Comment: Most people I have talked to use VIM or Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question, but FYI, there is a windows installer which does work and you can find it linked on this page: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Supported-Platforms. I had one of the meteor samples up and running on windows in minutes. From there I guess you can use Visual Studio or whatever you would normally use on windows.